# HtmlAgilityPack : Issues getting content of anchor tag within a string

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Guys what i'm trying to do is I've a section of a html code listed below. I need the content within the anchor tag.

```
HtmlDocument newHtml = new HtmlDocument();
newHtml.OptionOutputAsXml = true;

var content = "<div class="business-name-container">
            <span class="tier_info"></span>
                <h3 class="title fn org">
                    <a     href="http://www.abc.com/nationwide/mip/xyz?lid=161004592" class="url link">Foo</a>
                </h3>
            </div>";

newHtml.Load(content);
HtmlNode doc = newHtml.DocumentNode;
var findContent = doc.SelectNodes("//a[@class='url link']");
foreach (var aContent in findContent)
{
   if (acontent.InnerHtml != null)
    {
           Console.WriteLine("Content: " + acontent.InnerHtml);
    }
}
```

But i'm not getting the results.
I want to the output to be as "Content : Foo"

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
Console.WriteLine("Content: " + acontent.InnerHtml);
```

With

```
Console.WriteLine("Content: " + acontent.InnerText);
```

Or even better something like this

```
var result = acontent.DocumentNode
             .Descendants("a")
             .Where(x=>x.Attributes["class"].Value =="url link").InnerText;
```

Comment: Now I'm getting error "Illegal characters in path " on the line newHtml.Load(content);

is is necessary to convert the string to HtmlDocument ??? can't we get the data directly from the string ???

Comment: You're example is using html agility pack, therfore that is what my answer uses..

Comment: Sorry Zach m not getting where the bug is. Actually m new in c# and m confused in the mid of my project where to go now. Still thank you for you time and help. Thanks a lot Zach.